# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'dnn_DetectionModel'

Tags: python, opencv

Why do I get the error `AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'dnn_DetectionModel' when I try to run this code:

```
# get the weight configurations
 configPath = 
 '/Users/Rodne/MyComputerVision/Folder3/ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt'
weightsPath = '/Users/Rodne/MyComputerVision/Folder3/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# setting the bounding box
net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath, configPath)
net.setInputSize(320, 320)
```

**Error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-355122b5b70e> in <module>()
      1 # setting the bounding box
----> 2 net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath, configPath)
      3 net.setInputSize(320, 320)

AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'dnn_DetectionModel'
```

I have upgraded my open cv by typing this in the terminal: `pip install  opencv-python --upgrade`
and this was the result

```
Collecting opencv-python
  Downloading opencv_python-4.4.0.42-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (33.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 33.5 MB 54 kB/s
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.14.5 in d:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.18.5)
Installing collected packages: opencv-python
Successfully installed opencv-python-4.4.0.42
```

This is the only cv2.dnn I have:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to install OpenCV_contrib to use the DNN functionality which can be done with the link below I would suggest using the CMAKE gui

[Link with the steps to build opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib)

Comment: I don't have issues with the paths for the configPath and weightsPath. My error is  the cv2.dnn_DetectionModel does not exist.

Comment: I have had the exact error before could you try adding the full path.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still I get the same error...

Comment: What I can't figure out is why don't I have the `dnn_DetectionModel` attribute in my `cv2`

Comment: Did you add in opencv_contrib? The DNN functionality is not in the standard build of OpenCV.

Comment: I am very very new in opencv and python. How do I install the opencv_contrib?

Comment: That is the issue then. I will edit the question with the link to do so.

Comment: I did the `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: Ah yes you could do that as well. The one I linked above does it for both Python and C++ .

Comment: Ok I have not used the one you used, could you try with the link I shared?

Comment: Jeez.. Can't figure out the instructions in the link...

Comment: This will help and yes it is difficult to setup 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIpTks0G2m0

Answer (score 2):

You can also try updating the opencv module once. It worked in my case, after I updated my opencv module to opencv 4. Try running this command and see if it works:

```python
pip install --upgrade opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

use

`net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(weightsPath,configPath)`

instead of

`net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath, configPath)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).